# which technology to developp web based application?

Tags: web, web-applications

I would like to know which technologies are used to develop rich web based applications like 123d.circuits.io or others. 
I'm a web developper and i'm used to work with php/jquery/nodejs/angular etc.. But some application seems to be more 'client side', exactly like a desktop app. Any ideas ?

Comment: The site you have mentioned they using svg. I suggest you to study canvas, svg and choose what suits you for the kind of application you are building.

Comment: You can use J2EE(struts, JSF, ..) or another technology like ASP.NET with c#, VB or whatever you want for the backend, with all of them you can still use javascript and css3 for the frontend design.